# How to dynamically add clickable HyperLinkField inside gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a clickable link field dynamically inside my gridview. My code is

```
 while (rdr.Read())
        {
            DataRow dr = dtTutorial.NewRow();
            dr["Topic"] = rdr["Topic"];
            dr["Description"] = rdr["Description"];
            HyperLinkField h = new HyperLinkField();
            h.HeaderText = "Visit";
            h.NavigateUrl = "Details.aspx";
            h.DataTextField = rdr["link"].ToString();

            dr["Link"] = h;
            dtTutorial.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

But when I am executing this page, I am not getting the filed clickable. How can i resolve this?

Comment: Put your code for adding hyperlink in Row_DataBound event of grid view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. The code is given here

```
 while (rdr.Read())
        {
            DataRow dr = dtTutorial.NewRow();
            dr["Topic"] = rdr["Topic"];
            dr["Description"] = rdr["Description"];
            dr["Visit"] = rdr["id"];
            dtTutorial.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dtTutorial;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();
        hp.Text = "Click here";
        hp.NavigateUrl = "~/Details.aspx?id=" + gr.Cells[2].Text;
        gr.Cells[2].Controls.Add(hp);
    }
```